# initializing pointers to vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

We got two vectors in the form of

```
   vector<int>* v1; 
   v1->push_back(0); v1->push_back(1); 

   vector<int>* v2;  
   v2->push_back(2); v2->push_back(3);
```

now, how can I initialize a vector of vector with v1 and v2

my vector of vector looks like

```
  vector<vector<int> >* v2d1;
```

Comment: `vector<vector<int> > myvec(Y_SIZE, vector<int>(X_SIZE));`

Comment: Do you want instead `vector<vector<int>*> v2d1;` ?

Comment: Given the code you have shown, I am pretty sure you don't really need pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using pointers in first place, but here's how to :

```
vector<int>* v1  = new vector<int> () ; 
v1->push_back(0); v1->push_back(1); 

vector<int>* v2 = new vector<int>() ;  
v2->push_back(2); v2->push_back(3);

vector<vector<int> >* v2d1 = new vector<vector<int> > { *v1, *v2 } ;

// Stuffs


delete v1 ;
delete v2;
delete v2d1;
```

Comment: I guess he actually wants `vector<vector<int>*> v2d1 = { v1, v2 };`

Comment: @anu how is your `v2d1` declared ? Also is this heading toward [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232397) ?